# Как разобрать неправильный массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Мой код:

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> int(25) ["username"]=> string(14) "test2034f83366" }
```

Comment: Что значит "разобрать"?

Comment: @user263096 необходимо получить значение `id` и `username` в переменные. на примере это `25` и `test2034f83366`.

Comment: Код, который Вы указали в вопросе, не может являться кодом php скрипта. Это может быть результат его работы - вывод в браузер информации о переменной. Скиньте, пожалуйста, код php файла.

Answer (score 0):

В одну строчку, с помощью функции [extract](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php)

```
$arr = ["id" => 25, "username" =>  "test2034f83366" ];
extract($arr);
```

Результат:

```
var_dump($id);        # int(25)
var_dump($username);  # string(14) "test2034f83366"
```

Comment: Ответ приходит только в таком формате `array(2) { ["id"]=> int(25) ["username"]=> string(14) "test2034f83366" }`

Comment: Откуда приходит? Это строка, она хранится в переменной?

Comment: Хранится в переменной `$user`. Ответ приходит после API-запроса к Moodle.

Comment: Скиньте, пожалуйста, код файла, где у Вас описана эта переменная.

Comment: Хочу заметить, что использование extract - это плохая практика написания программного кода, когда происходит работа с переменными, которые до этого не были явно объявлены. Это приводит к усложнению отладки и чтению кода, тяжело понять откуда взялась эта переменная или почему существующая поменялась (в случае определенных флагов). Советую вам работать с объявлением переменных явно.